# How to set VPC flow logs in GCP as always on?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

> In GCP, by default VPC flow log is set as disabled (off).
>
> I am looking for some procedure through which whenever any member of
> my team creating VPC its flow log should be enable for every projects
> in single organization.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot enable VPC flow logs on organization level with the standard method, but you can try creating a python script to update all the VPC's to enable flow log.

Comment: Is there any automation through which I can achieve this scenario.. if yes please help with the steps.

Comment: You can use the API

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-flow-logs#enable-logging-existing